# complex custom model binding in aspnet core with inheritance in property's class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to do custom model binding in Core(2.2/3.1) with an inherited sub class.

I use [IModelBinderProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinderprovider) and [IModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinder) to manipulate my model binding as MVC doesn't know whether to translate the base class `Device` to a `Teddybear` or a `Legobrick`.

`IModelBinder`'s `BindModelAsync` method gets called for my `Product` class and I guess that is where I should look for the `Data` property and check its `Kind`. Then from the parameter `bindingContext.Model` extrude the Device data and replace the `Data` property's value with a `Teddybear` or `Legobrick`.
But `bindingContext.Model` is null; I have no data.

There is an example at towards the bottom of [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but in it, it is the root that is the base class.
I have a regular root but a property is a base/inherited class construct.

Somewhere I don't get the calls correctly hooked up or I haven't found the correct way to read data.

---

I guess my `IModelBinderProvider` is correct, it catches the `Product` type and adds binders to the sub classes `Teddybear` and `Legobrick`.

```
public class DeviceTypeDataContractProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        var binders = new Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)>();

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Product))
        {
            foreach (var type in new[] { typeof(Teddybear), typeof(Legobrick) })
            {
                var modelMetadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);
                binders[type] = (modelMetadata, context.CreateBinder(modelMetadata));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new DeviceModelBinder(binders);
    }
}
```

The code at `IModelBinder`/`BindModelAsync` still eludes me.

```
public class DeviceModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders;

    public DeviceModelBinder(Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders)
    {
        this.binders = binders;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext){
        ... I totally lost it here and am beginning to feel dizzy.
    }
}
```

Over internet comes a call like:

```
"product": {
    "id": "56-1",
    "data": {
        "kind": "teddy",
        "name": "Tutu"
    }
}
```

or

```
"product": {
    "id": "66-1",
    "data": {
        "kind": "lego",
        "studCount": 8
    }
}
```

which Aspnet uses to populate:

```
public class Product{
    string Id {get;set;}
    Device Data{get;set;}
}
public class Device{
    string Kind {get;set}
}
public class Teddybear: Device{
    string Name {get;set}
}
public class Legobrick: Device{
    int StudCount {get;set}
}
```

The controller is regular and the custom modelling is hooked up:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Product product){...
```

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    ...
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
.AddJsonOptions(options => {
     options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new DeviceTypeDataContractProvider());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution provided in documentation won't work in your case because of you using `json`. A simple working example would be

```
public class DeviceTypeDataContractProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Product))
        {
            return new DeviceModelBinder();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class DeviceModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body));
        //loading request json
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        JToken data = jObject["data"];

        Product result = jObject.ToObject<Product>();
        switch (result.Data.Kind)
        {
            case "teddy":
                result.Data = data.ToObject<Teddybear>();
                break;
            case "lego":
                result.Data = data.ToObject<Legobrick>();
                break;
            default:
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang! I was convinced the `IModelBinder` was the way to go.  My plan was to let Aspnet parse whatever-format-comes-in and handle data conversions at a "dotnet level". Do you, or anyone, know where to step in to get a more dotnet-ish object to handle?

Comment: @LosManos Not sure what you mean by ` at a "dotnet level"`. As you can see in my answer `IModelBinder ` **is** the way to go since the answer relies on it. Anyways, if you want to create a custom binding you'll still need to use `IModelBinder`

Comment: I was hoping to receive a dotnet `Product` object with `Data` set to `Device` which's `Kind` property I would read and then convert `Data` to `Teddybear` or `Legobrick`. It seems I am forced to handle Json, which means I might have to handle XML and whatever else is sent over the wire - something Aspnet usually handles for me.